# Indent nested calls using serilog

Tags: c#, serilog

Is it possible to indent logs in serilog for nested calls? So I would get the following:

```html
Function A...
  Function B...
```

If it matters I am using .net framework 4.7

Comment: TLDR no;serilog does not track the necessary context to provide such a mechanism (it's also not a common feature in a logging system as it would be difficult to implement efficiently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved in comment by Ruben